# Simple MYSQL insert statement not working, what am i NOT seeing

Tags: mysql

This is what I currently have, super basic. Still cant get it working :/

```
 $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
    or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
 $db = mysql_select_db("streetRider",$connection)
    or die ("Couldn't select database");




 $result = mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO video(id, parent_id, video, coverImage, 
    ts_created, is_void) VALUES('%s','%s','%s', '%s', '%s','%s')", $unique_id,           $parent_id,$videoDirectory,$imageDirectory,  $ts_created,  $is_void));

 What am i Missing???? :(
```

OK Guys so if one of my variables I'm storing is equal to this it works:

```
    $videoDirectory = 'userVideos/'.$unique_id;
```

When my variable is equal to this, the insert FAILS:
            $videoDirectory = 'userVideos/'.$unique_id.'.mp4';

Its really puzzling and frustrating, but thats what I figured out.video is datatype varchar(50).

Comment: What is the error message generated by MySQL?

Comment: What is "query"? A function that you wrote yourself? How does it handle errors?

Comment: A function I found online, and works for other inserts. It only returns this if the query failed('error'=>'Database error');

Comment: What language are you working in? I assume PHP because of the dollar signs, but that definitely has a native mysql function, which you should be able to get the error from

Comment: I think I will just not use that function and instead write an insert statement see what happens

Comment: you  missed `sprintf()` call

Comment: I started using native mysql function, I still cant get it working :(

Comment: `mysql_*()` functions are deprecated. Better use `mysqli_()` or PDO, and use their prepared statement stuff. If you can't, use at least `mysql_real_escape_string()` in order to sanitize your input.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? It throws an error? We need to see the error message. Or do you mean it has unexpected behavior? What did you expect? What is it doing instead? Why do you think what it is doing is not what you expect?

Comment: Dour, I edited my question. Its really strange whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned the columns with `%s` but your `query` function does have the `sprintf()` call in it? Try this

```
$result = mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO video(id, parent_id, video, coverImage, 
ts_created, is_void) 
VALUES('%s','%s','%s', '%s', '%s','%s')",
$unique_id, $parent_id,$videoDirectory,$imageDirectory,  $ts_created,  $is_void));
```

[**sprintf manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

---

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

i dont know you are using prepared statment or mysql anyway if you are tagged mysql then try this

```
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO video(id, parent_id, video, coverImage, ts_created, is_void) VALUES ($unique_id, $parent_id,$videoDirectory,$imageDirectory,  $ts_created,  $is_void ) ")
```

Comment: echo_ME, I got it working when I edited one of the variables.

Comment: Thank YOu, if I omit '.mp4' it WORKS. Really WEIRD.  $videoDirectory = 'userVideos/'.$unique_id.'.mp4';